# Plagiarizing problem sets and homework

Tags: education, plagiarism, homework

I am a young student checking pupils homeworks.
I've got a case - 2 pupils definetely cooperated when doing homework.
Do you have tips to determine who actually solved it and who copied? Got some ideas myself (like maybe one who copied had a better handwriting) but it is better to ask.

Comment: This isn't directly related to academia, but it is related to "life as a graduate student", as we've all been there. I personally vote to leave this open.

Comment: Wow. That sounds completely ridiculous, and your idea discriminates against students with nice handwriting. I believe that if you copy in a hurry, your handwriting becomes worse. Better to schedule a meeting and ask them upfront, instead of randomly accusing your own students.

Comment: This is homework, so I believe there was enough time for copying.

Comment: I've changed the title of the question, since it is not at all physics-specific.

Comment: _This isn't directly related to academia_ — Say what?? Of course this is directly related to academia!

Comment: What does the syllabus say about collaboration on homework? This is enormously relevant. In my courses I _encourage_ collaboration on homework, knowing that the student who merely copies will fail the exams.

Comment: Well, up to date it says nothing. I have always been thinking that copying = cheating, because ranks depend on marks, and couldn't imagine that this must be additionally mentioned.

Comment: @JeffE - I guess I meant it's not *specifically* academia-related; this question applies to any teaching institution. Still, it does work here.

Comment: And teaching institutions (or as they are sometimes called, _academies_) aren't academia?  What dictionary are _you_ using?

Comment: Before you take any action, make sure you know the rules of academic integrity at your school. Many institutions have very strict rules to follow regarding the handling of suspected plagiarism, because of the legal implications.

Comment: What Fuhrmanator says. Many institutions only require the course leader to flag cases of suspected academic offences and produce evidence. Then the actual investigation of if and what AO happened will be carried out by a separate committee. This ensures that the university's AO policy is enforced in a fair and consistent manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my anecdotal experience for dealing with copiers and plagiarizers. At the end of the day, everyone should be penalized. It's just a matter of sorting out who did what, and making sure they're aware that further offending can carry severe consequences.

If discussing problems in groups is okay and encouraged (it should be!), don't forget to reinforce this. Just stress that the solutions themselves must be individual work.

- The weaker piece of homework (i.e. less complete explanations and working, or missing parts) is likely to be written by the student who had no contribution (or a lesser contribution) to the solution.
- It's usually rather obvious that some copying has gone on, especially if they all make the same mistakes and lay out their working the same. Consider rounding up all the students and talking to them together to find out the full story. They've already been caught red-handed, so it's in their best interests to be honest with you!
- It's important to find out exactly what happened, because there are cases where someone has copied work without the other's knowledge. In this case, it's not fair to punish both parties.
- If the student doing the copying has accidentally written their friend's name or student number on the sheet rather than their own, that tends to be a dead give-away that it's a downright facsimile of other work (that has actually happened).

Comment: Not always true - I've seen copiers who expand on the work they copied

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'd say that if they expanded on the copying, that's better than straight-up copying, so I wouldn't worry too much about penalizing them less.

Comment: @AlexBecker, consider a scenario where I do all my work by myself, and you copy my work but expand on it. Mine is the weaker solution, and following this advice I am more of a suspect.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Fair point. I suppose I also hadn't thought of the possibility that the work was copied without permission.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi May I suggest you read my answer more carefully? I do say that the weaker piece is *likely* written by the copier, not always. But unless (this possibility I also mention) the work is copied without the knowledge of the "victim", each student should be disciplined equally and so the point of who did more actual work is unimportant.

Comment: @Moriarty, most definitely both should be given a hearing before handing out punishment, but to be honest, one will tend to think the weaker solution belongs to the copier, and hence the _"he stole my work"_ consideration will be applied incorrectly.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Indeed a private discussion is necessary. earthling's answer describes the two choices well. A student is innocent until they admit their guilt (or it is proven beyond reasonable doubt). If an amicable discussion doesn't result in an admitted consensus as to who did what, or both students deny any wrongdoing yet copying *almost* certainly occurred (sometimes there's only so many ways to skin a cat), then I think that the case is outside the jurisdiction of a TA.

Answer (score 10):

Although I do not teach physics I do have a solution that generally works quite well.

The main answer is: **It does not matter who copied from whom - fail both.**

If one student allows another to copy, then both fail. I enforce this quite strictly and there are some students (who do not pay attention to the warnings I give at the start of the semester) who do it, but they never make the same mistake twice.

As Moriarty said, it is possible that Student B copied from Student A without Student A knowing about it. I solve this problem but calling them both in front of me (private from everyone else) and tell them they have a choice:

Choice A: Both admit that the copying took place with consent of both, and both fail that homework/assignment/test/whatever is being assessed.

Choice B: Student A says that Student B stole Student A's work, and Student A gets off with a warning to be more careful (but no punishment) and Student B fails the module immediately without the opportunity to recover (Student B must re-take the module from the beginning).

I have dealt with many cases this way and only three cases where the students ended up in Choice B. In this case, the offending students admitted that they stole work.

You should never support the student who allows another student to copy from them. That behavior is simply unacceptable and that needs to be made quite clear to everyone.

Comment: If you don't have an official plagiarism policy in your syllabus, failing a student for a course because of a plagiarized assignment is excessively harsh. It is perfectly fair, however, to give them zero credit __for the assignment__.

Comment: There's also a privacy/FERPA problem with this approach.  If student A is honestly unaware that any copying took place, I _cannot_ identify student B as the plagiarist to student A. (I faced exactly this situation two months ago.)

Comment: @aeismail I do mention it in the syllabus. Of course students must know the rules at the start. I have yet to see any student call me unfair...even behind my back. Strict, yes. But never unfair.

Comment: @JeffE You cannot highlight a block of text and say it also exists in Student B's paper? What privacy rule are you violating?

Comment: No, I cannot.  The fact that a student has been found guilty of cheating, or is being investigated for cheating, is itself a FERPA-protected educational record.  Formally, _even the fact that a student is registered for my course_ is a FERPA-protected educational record. The most I can say is "This block of text appears verbatim in another student's submission".

Comment: @earthling In physics, it's fairly common (at least more common than in your field, or so I'd guess from the way you wrote this answer) to allow collaborative work, which tends to result in multiple students submitting near-identical solutions. Depending on the nature of the class, the policy of automatically failing anyone who submits work that appears to have been copied may not be realistic. (Whereas it certainly seems appropriate for e.g. an English class.)

Answer (score 7):

I am surprised that no one mentioned this solution yet, but it shouldn't be too difficult to find out by interrogating them: question them both on how they solved the exercises. "So, tell me, which formula are you applying in this line? Why are the hypotheses satisfied? Show me the missing steps."

Answer (score 1):

I have also got in that situation with a couple of students that I was lecturing. I decided to fail both and sent an email, to both of them, saying that they were going to be penalized even with the disciplinary committee of the University to expelled them both. In a couple of hours the person that was guilty confesses his participation in this situation. I only decided to fail that person from the exam and leave the other only with a disciplinary warning.

Long story short: Here you have only two ways, either you fail both of them which is simpler; or just look for the guilty person (which I usually do and I always discover the sinner")

Good luck!

Comment: I would argue a student has committed an offence by allowing / supporting the copying. Punishing only the copier tells other students it is ok to share as long as you are the original author. Seems a bad policy to me.

Comment: What if both students profess ignorance?  (Yes, I've seen this happen.)  Are you happy with the possibility that one of the students may be expelled even though the plagiarism happened without their cooperation or consent?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should remember that you are a teacher, and that you are responsible for your students' intellectual growth.

If you decide to randomly accuse one of the two students of "copying", and if you are wrong, then think about the effects that this accusation could have. Aside from the hurt feelings, that student could lose confidence, since your accusation shows that you think that this student is worse than the student who copied. There is no predicting how your actions could change the students' lives. Honestly, from your posts, it seems like you are almost trying to make this a bigger deal than it actually is.

The standard way to deal with this situation is to have a meeting with both students, and to put both students through the same disciplinary action, unless one student confesses that he copied from the other student, in which case the punishment level could be adjusted.

But the thing that shocked me the most from this post is the fact that you apparently seem comfortable with randomly accusing your own students. You should remember that you have HUGE effects on their lives, and make sure that you do not abuse it. Showing mistrust is one thing that you should never, never do to your students.

Comment: I don't understand how you decided what I am comfortable with. If I would, I wouldn't ask this question at all. And the question is to make this as mush less random as possible (if possible, of course!). If I won't find a very clear indication of who did that, I will speak with both, for sure.

Comment: The accusatory tone of this answer is not helpful or appropriate.

Comment: Yes, a bit, but it stresses the responsibility part, so it's ok.